# Visual Studio 2013 wont run as administrator

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to get Visual Studio 2013 running as an administrator, but I'm constantly getting errors.  I've searched and tried solutions for other versions of VS, but those fixes didn't apply, so hopefully someone here can help.

When I try to run VS2013 as an admin, I an error saying that the application cannot start.

I saw a few articles talking about copying and registering dte*.olb files, but they were for previous versions of VS. I copied one of the files over and registered it and I can now get past the original error, but I can't compile any application - including any default template workspaces. Before I went too crazy and potentially made things worse, I wanted to ask here.

If I don't get the "application cannot start" message, I get this message when I try to compile anything:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The problem is that that error code doesn't tell me what library wont load.

The output window says:

```
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))
1>------ Build started: Project: WcfService1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  WcfService1 -> C:\Users\David\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WcfService1\WcfService1\bin\WcfService1.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling NuGet with no change in the behavior.

And if I go to the project properties, I can't see the Web, Package/Publish Web, or Code Analysis Tabs.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

This is on Windows 8.1 Pro.  My exact VS configuration is below.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641

Installed Version: Professional

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0444002-02105
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013

Microsoft Office Developer Tools - Update 1 for Visual Studio 2013 ENU   06177-004-0444002-02105
Microsoft Office Developer Tools - Update 1 for Visual Studio 2013 ENU

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0444002-02105
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013

Visual Basic 2013   06177-004-0444002-02105
Microsoft Visual Basic 2013

Visual C# 2013   06177-004-0444002-02105
Microsoft Visual C# 2013

Visual C++ 2013   06177-004-0444002-02105
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013

Visual F# 2013   06177-004-0444002-02105
Microsoft Visual F# 2013

Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker   06177-004-0444002-02105
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU   06177-004-0444002-02105
Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU

ASP.NET and Web Tools   2013.1.41009
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Support for creating and opening ASP.NET web projects
Browser Link: A communication channel between Visual Studio and browsers
Editor extensions for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
Page Inspector: Inspection tool for ASP.NET web projects
Scaffolding: A framework for building and running code generators
Server Explorer extensions for Windows Azure Web Sites
Web publishing: Extensions for publishing ASP.NET web projects to hosting providers, on-premises servers, or Windows Azure

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.21001.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.0.11213.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.0
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Windows Azure Tools.

JetBrains ReSharper 8.1   Full Edition build 8.1.23.546 on 2013-12-12T07:30:52
JetBrains ReSharper 8.1 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/. Copyright © 2003–2014 JetBrains, Inc.

Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone   
Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone
Build 

NuGet Package Manager   2.8.50126.477
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.30919.1
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Visual Studio Spell Checker   VSSpellChecker
An editor extension that checks the spelling of comments, strings, and plain text as you type.

Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.0
Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools

Windows Azure Remote Debugging   1.0
Windows Azure Remote Debugging Community Technology Preview

Windows Azure Tools   2.2
Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - v2.2.11003.1601

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.
```

Comment: Quick question, is this computer being controlled by any group policies that might be restricting you running the program as an administrator?

Comment: No, it's a stand alone computer that's just part of it's own Workgroup.  No AD, policies, etc.  There's actually just one user and that's the account I'm logged in as.

Comment: If i am not wrong, Visual Studio 2013 has two extra modes, Safe Mode and Diagonistics mode. Have you ever tried these modes? Also i suggest you open bug at microsoft connect. One time i had been joined a mail loop in Visual Studio developers for a strange problem and i sware i couldn't think to look some folders and file contents without their help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And I'll go with the saddest answer of all time: Have you tried a full uninstall, reboot and re-install of Visual Studio?

This will also help if the issue is as a result of an add-in or similar.

I had a lot of issues with a clean install of VS2013 on win7 (projects not loading, crashes etc). A re-install sadly was the only thing that helped.  This is poor advice I know but still sometimes one of the best fixes to some VS ills.

[EDIT]
I am no fan of fixing up failed installs unless it breaks the same every time.
Refer [Connect Article](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/472443/visual-studio-startup-error-when-run-as-administrator-application-cannot-start) (For VS2012 but same issue).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899210/visual-studio-project-properties-tab-web-missing) Stack Overflow question may help with the crashes. The question is for VS2008 but it looks identical.  Try and reset your fonts as suggested.  (I think running Devenv /ResetSettings at a minimum is not a bad idea)

Comment: This is almost a new build as it is.  I just reinstalled and reconfigured Windows, so there isn't much extraneous stuff on here.  I can try a reinstall of just VS if I can't figure out what else it might be.

Comment: Sorry I did mean just a re-install of VS.

Comment: Well, in the end the reinstall worked.  I tried a bunch of other fixes, but reinstalling actually fixed the issue and turned out not to be as much of a headache as I anticipated.  All of the settings stayed and the old projects loaded with no hiccups.

Comment: I can't believe I just gave a 100 point bounty for "reinstall" answser! ;)

Comment: I told you it was the saddest answer of all time :)

Comment: Nah, it's not that bad.  You're right about not trying to fix installations that go bad, so I wanted to flag this as the answer to remind anyone else to reinstall first and then try fixes if the reinstall doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I do recommend to disable Resharper. From time to time I meet a VS solution which I can't open in VS2013 with enabled ReSharper.

```
Tools->Options->Resharper->Suspend Now
```

Comment: This didn't seem to help, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

It will be difficult to help without some information such as 
 - Event log for the error 
 - Further details of the error message ("Application cannot start" is a bit vague)

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm not trying to write one of those "Iz broken! Plz help!!!!11!" posts, but there isn't much to go on which is why I wanted to ask before just randomly trying fixes for other versions of VS that are likely to make things worse.  When I launch the application as an administrator, I get the "Application cannot start" message.  If I copy the OLB file over, I get it to launch, but then I get the error [I just added] above whenever I try to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Have you rebooted since installing ?
Have you updated via windows update yet ?

Did you install it to its usual path or somewhere else ?
Did you install it as admin or under a user account ?

If its work pc is it installed locally or under a roaming profile ?

No problems on my surface pro or desktop running it as admin or standard user
but it is installed locally and was installed under my developer account but works under all accounts (test ,dev,admin, user etc)

Comment: I did reboot and there are no Windows Updates left to install.  It was installed in the default path when I was logged in as my user account which is an admin account on a local profile.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, I believe there is an issue with Microsoft Office Developer Tools specifically Outlook related.

**Fix 1:**

Checking your Office directory for msoutl.olb.  If it is there, try running 'regtlib msoutl.olb'.  You should have regtlib on your machine is part of your Visual Studio install, I believe.  Anyway, reregistering the typelib will rewrite all of the necessary keys to the registry.  You will need administrative privileges for this operation.

**Fix 2:**

Try running a program that came with Outlook - C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\MSMAPI\1033\Scanpst.exe

For more information please see this site - [Click Here](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/outlook/repair.html)

**Fix 3:**

Try uninstalling Office Developer Tools and see if the problem persists.

**Fix 4:**

The other possibility is that msoutl.olb itself is corrupt, in which case reinstalling Outlook should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could be windows 8 acting up. Saying that, insure that your OS is updated, new patches to fix broken stuff should be regular, i suspect a lot of broken things.

Insure that you have the correct .net framework installed and re-install it if necessary. I am not too familiar with Windows 8, i had 3 months of an unpleasant experience with it, but try to see if you can change the compatibility mode by right clicking on the .exe file.

i doubt my response would be any better than others but i felt like contributing and since no one mentioned either checking the .net framework or the compatability..

best of luck!

also i did a small bit of research into TYPE_E_cantloadlibrary and found this link, maybe you should check it out
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac50fa41-8d47-4fa9-81a3-914f262676af/0x80029c4a-typeecantloadlibrary?forum=vsto

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. right click devenv.exe
2. troubleshoot compatibility
3. Troubleshoot program
4. This program requires addition permission
5. Next
6. Test the program
7. Next
8. Yes, save these settings for this program.

This will make VS run as administrator from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem. My issue was that the 'Start Page' was fowled up.
I've edited the following:

```
> Tools > Options > Startup
```

Choose 'Show empty environment' in the 'At startup' pulldown

This fixed all my problems and can run as Administrator again.